# Scraping a website with form and JS using R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm tryng to scrape a website that have a form and that generates the information I want from JS (I guess).

This is the website: https://www.distancecalculator.net/ , it calculates the distance between cities.

For instance, I want to calculate the distance between these two cities:

- Craíbas - AL, Brasil
- Maceió - AL, Brasil

It seems that, even though I'm using the POST to fill the form, my scraper is still collecting the data available from before clicking the "Calculate" button. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.distancecalculator.net/"

fd <- list(
  submit = "Calculate Distance",
  "originCity"  = "Craíbas - AL, Brasil",
  "destinationCity" = "Maceió - AL, Brasil"
)

resp<-POST(url, body=fd, encode="form")
conte <- content(resp)
conte

tex <- conte %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//span[@id="driving-distance-km"]/text()') %>% html_text()
tex
```

Comment: If you are looking to calculate distances between cities.  I suggest you look at R options like the geosphere package and the maps package has a dataset of world.cities.  These packages could suit your needs.

Comment: There are a number of other posts that might help if you search something like "scrape form" under the `r` tag--maybe not exact duplicates, but some answers that might help. You also might check out RSelenium, which is built for this type of task

Comment: I've looked many other posts like this but none seem to help me :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment that RSeleneium would be the best for this. Here is your desired result using RSelenium.

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- "https://www.distancecalculator.net/"

#Start Selenium
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = "chrome")
remDr <- rD$client 
remDr$navigate(url)

#Type in the information
originCity <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#originCity")
originCity$sendKeysToElement(list("Craíbas - AL, Brasil"))
#Click the first item
clickFirst <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", ".pac-item")
clickFirst2 <- unlist(lapply(clickFirst, function(x){
  x$getElementText()
}))
clickFirst2
click <- clickFirst[[which(clickFirst2 == clickFirst2[1])]]
click$clickElement()

destinationCity <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#destinationCity")
destinationCity$sendKeysToElement(list("Maceió - AL, Brasil"))
#Click the first item
clickFirst <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", ".pac-item")
clickFirst2 <- unlist(lapply(clickFirst, function(x){
  x$getElementText()
}))
clickFirst2
click <- clickFirst[[which(clickFirst2 == clickFirst2[1])]]
click$clickElement()

#No longer Necessary 
calculate <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", '//*[contains(concat( " ", 
@class, " " ), concat( " ", "button", " " ))]')
calculate2 <- unlist(lapply(calculate, function(x){
   x$getElementText()
 }))
calculate2
click <- calculate[[which(calculate2 == calculate2[1])]]
click$clickElement()

#Scrape the result
dist <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "#driving-distance-km")
dist <- unlist(lapply(dist, function(x){
  x$getElementText()
}))
dist
remDr$close()
```

And a link to the RSelenium package information: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html

Comment: Hey, really interesting code. I tried it on my machine, and the locations filled in the boxes, but they didn't check the first occurrence, which it asks for in the website. So when it clicks calculate I get "0 km" whatever I put in for the cities. Does this happen for you?

Comment: No I did not get this. However, I've updated the code so that it clicks on the first location in the box when we type it in. Notice when we do this we no longer need to run the line that clicks on the calculate box.

Comment: Hey, nice approach. However, the line 15 gives me the following error: Error in lapply(calculate, function(x) { : object 'calculate' not found
I guess the 'calculate' is something from the previous version of your code.

Comment: Sorry about that. You are correct it was. I have fixed it

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jordan. I'm really interested in learning more about scrapers. Do you suggest any particular book or online course? I've done just basic stuff on this subject.

Comment: I learned based upon questions I saw on here/Github. If you're looking to scrape more I'd recommend using Python over R. This post has some good packages to try out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping?rq=1